# Topology of Uniform Convergence and Compact-Open Topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, definition, uniform-convergence

Let $\mathbb{R}^i$ be equipped with their Euclidean topologies (for $i=n,m$) and consider the following topologies on $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$:

**Topology of Pointwise convergence**
In Nagata's book, it is shown that the topology of pointwise convergence is equivalent to the point-open topology, which is generated by the sub-basic sets
$$
\left\{f \in C(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m) : f(x) \subseteq O \right\}, \quad x \in \mathbb R^n,\ O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \text{ open}.
$$

**Topology of Compact Convergence**
Similarly, in the same book, it is shown that the topology of *[compact-convergence (a.k.a. uniform convergence on compacts)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence)* is well-known to be equivalent to the compact-open topology on $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ which can be described by the sub-basic sets
$$
\left\{f \in C(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m) : f(K) \subseteq O \right\}, \quad K \subseteq \mathbb R^n \text{ compact, } O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \text{ open}.
$$

**Topology of Uniform Convergence**
From these equivalences one immediately has that compact convergence refines pointwise convergence.  Now, it is also clear that uniform convergence refines compact convergence.  Is there a sub-base of the topology of uniform convergence of the form
$$
\left\{
f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m):\, 
f(A) \subseteq O
\right\}, \quad A \in \mathcal{A}, \ O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m\mbox{ open},
$$
where $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{A}\subseteq 2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is a collection of non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: May be of interest: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864114003964 (but maybe not also...)

Comment: I don't think the topology of uniform convergence can be seen as a set-open topology. Just a hunch, no proof yet.

Comment: I would be interested either way.